# I added this Extension method to my code. It works but is flagged as an error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, extension-methods

I added this extension method to my code to try & get the Table name of tables accessed.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WfUnposted.Models
{
   public static class ContextExtensions
   {
       public static string GetTableName<T>(this DbContext context) where T : class
       {
           ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;

           return objectContext.GetTableName<T>();
       }

       public static string GetTableName<T>(this ObjectContext context) where T : class
       {
           string sql = context.CreateObjectSet<T>().ToTraceString();
           Regex regex = new Regex("FROM (?<table>.*) AS");
           Match match = regex.Match(sql);

           string table = match.Groups["table"].Value;
           return table;
       }
   }
}
```

I am calling it like this:

```
        using (ExchequerModel1 context = new ExchequerModel1())
        {
            string table = context.GetTableName<DETAIL>();
            Models.Logging.WriteLog("OurRef: " + ourRef + " Reading table: " + table);
```

It is working:

```
OurRef: POR033945 Reading table: [SHIR99].[DETAILS]
```

However, Visual Studio is undelining it in red, with this error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'ExchequerModel1' does not contain a definition for 'GetTableName' and no accessible extension method 'GetTableName' accepting a first argument of type 'ExchequerModel1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In spite of this, the code compiles and does exactly what I want.
How do I remove this error?

Note: The code came from here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/350135/Entity-Framework-Get-Mapped-Table-Name-from-an-Ent

Comment: The types expected for the extension methods are `DbContext` and `ObjectContext `, but you are trying to call `GetTableName` on the type `ExchequerModel1`.  You haven't shared the code for `ExchequerModel1` but it's not one of the two types the extension method is for.

Comment: Have you tried to restart Visual Studio?

Comment: `code compiles and does exactly what I want` this happens if Intelli Sense fails for some reason. You may turn intelliSense errors off (there is ComboBox in the Error Window, just set it to `Errors only`. Or you may try close the VS, locate `.vs` folder in the solution root (it is hidden and may not be visible) and delete the `.vs` folder (WARN you will lost breakpoints and other VS settings for the specific solution)  to reset IntelliSense cache